# Pseudo random permutation function in c++

Tags: c++, random, srand

I'm looking for a couple of function that works in a similar fashion of `srand(unsigned int)` and `rand(void)` but, with a variable range instead of a fixed one.

I don't like the script

```
srand(time(NULL));
random_number = rand() % (h_limit - l_limit) + l_limit;
```

for two reasons. The first one is that a number can be repeated. The second one is that, for large limits, the probability density function is not a costant.

I think that a good solution could be redefine `RAND_MAX` that is the upper limit of classical functions. Is this a good way to solve my problem or there might be problems? Have you a better way to proceed?

Comment: If a number can't be repeated, then it is not random.

Comment: @stark: You mean "less random"?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I guess I mean "not uniformly distributed".  It can't be random if it is from a PRNG.

Comment: If you require that ouputs are never repeated, then you want a pseudo-random permutation function, not a pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: Well, you can build it from a pseudo-random number generator. Or for short lists, just shuffle.

Comment: @stark: Sorry if i caused some misunderstanding. With `rand()`, only the number obtained from the first call is supposed to be "random". The number returned from the second call cannot be the same of the first one. In other words, is the order in which the numbers are given that is random. 

With the use of `rand()` in the the second line, instead, this property is no more true because there is a modulo operation.

Comment: @user3553031: you're right, i'll edit the question